# ST_MakeEnvelope with Google Maps Coordinates problem

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, postgis

In postgress I have the following function that uses `ST_MakeEnvelope` based on the Google Maps viewport coordinates to returns all projects within that viewport.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.search_projects_area(
  lngw double precision,
  lats double precision,
  lnge double precision,
  latn double precision
) RETURNS SETOF project_locations LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS $ function $
SELECT
  A.*
FROM
  project_locations A
WHERE
  st_intersects(
    A.location :: geography,
    ST_MakeEnvelope(lngw, lats, lnge, latn, 4326) :: geography
  ) $ function $
```

Below is how I get the coordinates to create the envelope:

```
const bounds = this.map.getBounds();
const sw = this.map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
const ne = this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
const lngw = sw.lng();
const lats = sw.lat();
const lnge = ne.lng();
const latn = ne.lat();
```

The problem is that projects in specific areas are not fetched sometimes depending on where I have the map zoomed or positioned. The projects are defenitely inside the viewport though in all cases.

Its as if the `ST_MakeEnvelope` method doesnt create the correct rectangle based on the map viewport.

Is my code above correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By casting to `geography`, the bounding box edges are created using great circle arcs instead of straight lines. Therefore, a point that **looks** inside the viewport (projected in 3857) may be outside of the box.

So either you do want to work with great circle arcs and it is a display issue, or you want to stick to what is displayed and you would need to remove the cast to `geography`

Comment: Do you mean I should remove the `:: georgaphy` part from this line `ST_MakeEnvelope(lngw, lats, lnge, latn, 4326) :: geography` only? Should I remove it from `A.location :: geography` also?

Comment: @ConstantinosN both

Comment: I made it work by also using `lat` in the place of `lng` and vice versa. Google Maps is considering `lat` as `x` and `lng` as `y` and thats how its saved in my database. I also casted `A.location` to geometry since it was originally geography in the DB. Source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78816/maximum-size-on-the-bounding-box-with-st-makeenvelope-and-and-geography-colum